# Reputation change on Android app feed - since any last activity, or since last app activity?

Tags: support, bug, reputation, android-app, android-app-feed

I'm not sure if this is a bug, which is why I tagged it as both [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

I haven't looked at the mobile app in a few days, but have done a lot (by my standards) on the desktop site. When I looked at the feed on app, it said +260 reputation on SO. This is clearly not the change that I got since my last SO activity - about 3 minutes prior on the desktop site.

I'm guessing it's the change since the last time I looked at the app feed. At least for me, it makes more sense for it to show the reputation change since last activity on any platform.

Is this a bug, or was there a compelling reason to have it display the change since last activity on this app only?

Comment: I think you're correct, last time since you visited the feed. Right now I have a story for +35 for a post, then a story for +5 for the exact same story before. But they are separate since I refreshed the feed. The devs may have a better answer, but it seems like it the feed is what's happening in that point in time. And they aren't going back and removing stories you may have seen from the feed.

Comment: Steven's comment should be correct: Android app feed is additive. It never deletes/updates existing feed entries (except status of question & total number of answers). Also, I replaced the [tag:discussion] tag to [tag:support], since it seems you're looking for support from SE devs for this question.